# Why isn't this AJAX request waiting?

Tags: ajax

I try to make an AJAX Request with JQuery to Flickr, get a single Images URL and return this src to process further, but JQuery doesn't wait, it returns always the default declaration of "":

```
function getFlickr(url){
var src = "";
var settings = $.extend({ 
    url : url,
    key : '61328c74e544a789b356a36aec03acfe',
    secret : 'f119e504140f0964'
    }),
    id,
    method = 'flickr.photos.getInfo',
    format = 'json',
id = settings.url.match(/\/photos\/(.*)/)[1].split('/')[1];
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method='+method+'&format='+format+'&api_key='+settings.key,
     async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'photo_id':id},
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonFlickrApi',
    success: function(data){
       src = 'http://farm'+data.photo.farm+'.static.flickr.com/'+data.photo.server+'/'+id+'_'+data.photo.secret+'.jpg';
         alert(src);  
            //$(this).append('<img src="http://farm'+data.photo.farm+'.static.flickr.com/'+data.photo.server+'/'+id+'_'+data.photo.secret+'.jpg">'); 
    }
});
return src;
}
```

And i call the functions with this:

```
lnk = getFlickr(url);
```

But i always get a "" Response, on Code Debugging i get the first Code Break with a wrong response, not inside the ajax success callback, what am i doing wrong?

thx for help

Comment: _“what am i doing wrong?”_ – you’re forcefully trying to make a _synchronous_ request – _why_?

Comment: Where and how to change this to be async?